# Capture upload file size in Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, selenium-chromedriver

Is it possible if I want to capture the file size after I uploaded the files using Selenium WebDriver? Btw I'm using Java. Currently I'm following this one tutorial & here's the code:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver; 

public class upload {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","webdriver location");
       String baseUrl = "http://demo.guru99.com/test/upload/";
       WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

       driver.get(baseUrl);
       WebElement uploadElement = driver.findElement(By.id("uploadfile_0"));

       // enter the file path onto the file-selection input field
       uploadElement.sendKeys("file location");

       // check the "I accept the terms of service" check box
       driver.findElement(By.id("terms")).click();

       // click the "UploadFile" button
       driver.findElement(By.name("send")).click();
       }
}
```

I want to print the file size output in console. May I know is this action is possible or not? Thanks.

Comment: You can do it without the need for selenium. Or you could use Autoit to get the name and then do it.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this? It prints the size of the file uploaded prior to uploading.

```
import java.io.File;
String fileName = "C:/users/something.txt";
File f = new File(fileName);
long fileSize = f.length();
System.out.format("The size of the file: %d bytes", fileSize);
```

Comment: those lines should be included in public class upload?

Comment: i added those lines, but i got red error at System.out.format line. not sure what's the problem

Comment: change file name.

Comment: already put the file name to mine. actually your code lines... where to put it ya? inside the  public class upload or above it?

Comment: inside main before you send keys.